# Adding new column in between existing columns according to data in a text file

Tags: c#, text-files

I'm adding data in text files to a datatable according to the method shown below: 
suppose these are the lines that I use in the 1st text file:

```
data1, data2

1,2
```

suppose these are the lines that I use in the 2nd text file:

```
data1, data2

3,4
```

I would insert them to a datatable as show below:

[image]

I have done the coding upto this point and it works successfully. The issue occurs when the 3rd text file contains data as shown below:

```
data1, data0, data2

5,6,7
```

at this instance i need to re arrange my datatable as shown below:

[image]

I tried many ways but it keeps on adding data only to the end of the datatable. Can somebody please help. I have provided my coding below:

```
private DataTable CreateDT1(string name, ListBox list)
    {            
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();          
        string[] files = new string[list.Items.Count];//text files are taken to a list box
        for (int x = 0; x < list.Items.Count; x++)
        {
            object s = list.Items[x];
            files[x] = s.ToString();
        }            
        int lineno = 0;                
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                int count = 0;  
                string file = files[i];
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file))
                {                                          
                    string line;                   
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {                            
                        if (line.Contains(name))//i'm filtering some lines containing a given string
                        {                                         
                            if (i == 0)
                            {                                    
                                if (lineno == 0)//first line in the first test file. Eg: data1,data2
                                {
                                    string[] split = line.Split(',');//splitting the line adding data to rows

                                    int result = split.Length;
                                    dt.Rows.Add();                                        
                                    for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                                    {
                                        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(x.ToString(), Type.GetType("System.String"));
                                        dt.Columns.Add(dc);                                            
                                        dt.Rows[lineno][x] = split[x];
                                    }                                                                            
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    string[] split = line.Split(',');//splitting the other lines in 1st text file and adding data to rows
                                    int result = split.Length;
                                    dt.Rows.Add();
                                        for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                                        {
                                            dt.Rows[lineno][x] = split[x];
                                        }                                                                            
                                }                                    
                            }

                            else
                            {                                    
                                if (count != 0)//for other (2nd, 3rd, ..)text files. This refers to the lines other than the 1st line(5,6,7). First line (data1, data0, data2)of these text files are not accounted here.
                                {
                                    string[] split = line.Split(',');
                                    int result = split.Length;                                        
                                        dt.Rows.Add();
                                        for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                                        {
                                            dt.Rows[lineno][x] = split[x];
                                        }                                           
                                }

                                else //this is the first line of other files
                                {
                                    string[] split = line.Split(',');
                                    int result = split.Length;
                                    if (result + 1 > dt.Columns.Count)//if existing number of columns are less than the split result of the first line, add new columns accordingly. I need help at this point
                                    {                                            
                                        for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                                        {
                                            Object a = dt.Rows[0][x];
                                            if (split[x] == Convert.ToString(a))
                                            {
                                                dt.Rows[0][x] = split[x];
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                dt.Columns.Add(x.ToString() + split[x]).SetOrdinal(x + 1);
                                                //dt.Columns.Add(x.ToString() + split[x]).SetOrdinal(x);
                                                dt.Rows[0][x.ToString() + split[x]] = split[x];
                                            }                                                
                                        }

                                        lineno -= 1;
                                        count += 1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        lineno -= 1;
                                        count += 1;
                                    }
                                }

                              }                                

                            lineno += 1;                                
                        }

                    }

                }

            }               

        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Columns are only added at the end, because otherwise it can mess up existing INSERT SQL queries.**

You should not be concerned about how the db organizes itself - that's the whole point!
later on just query out columns at your wanted order..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i dont understand how to query out the columns to the wanted order after adding the values to datatable. Could you please let me know how to implement it